# Efficient ways to calculate (-1)^n in C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I would like to know which are the most efficient methods to calculate (-1)^n in terms of bit operations and code length.

The following examples assume integer n:

```
int a=(n%2==0?1:-1);
int b=(n&1?-1:1);
```

I don't care about the ease of understanding the code.

Comment: Viewing the generated assembly or doing a benchmark would be a good start if you really care about this for performance.

Comment: In terms of code length `int a=(n%2?-1:1);` is better than `int a=(n%2==0?1:-1);`

Comment: A) Show me the benchmark that shows this is a bottleneck B) Show me the assembly that shows the compiler didnt optimize those to the same thing already

Comment: _"I don't care about the ease of understanding the code."_ LOL, Assembly masters chime in. Is that actually considered useful for future research?

Comment: `(-1)^n` is rarely used on its own. For instance, if you're calculating it as part of a convergent series, you're better off calculating two subsequent terms in each iteration. More context is needed to answer this X/Y question.

Comment: @Borgleader: well, I would hope those two particular statements wouldn't optimize to the same thing, side the second is a constant "-1" (the condition should be `n&1` to detect oddness. ;-)

Comment: There are going to be datasets with different best algorithms.  Without a description of the data, there is no "best".

Comment: @Kundor I assumed it was a typo on OPs part, otherwise it makes no sense to ask which two pieces of unrelated code is the fastest :)

Comment: @Kundor I thought that n&0 detected even numbers

Comment: @brubeck `n & 0` is always false, so it detects nothing

Answer (score 5):

With [gcc 6.1 both produce the same assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/Qr3DgV):

```
int f(int n) {
  return n % 2 ? -1 : 1;
}

int g(int n) {
  return n & 1 ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Assembly:

```
f(int):
        movl    %edi, %eax
        andl    $1, %eax
        negl    %eax
        orl     $1, %eax
        ret
g(int):
        movl    %edi, %eax
        andl    $1, %eax
        negl    %eax
        orl     $1, %eax
        ret
```

Which is equivalent to function:

```
int h(int n) {
  return -(n & 1) | 1;
}
```

Interestingly, gcc compilers 4.4.7 to 5.3 compile into longer assembly, the same for these versions.